# Inserting values from a UserForm to excel sheet which start from a fixed cell?

Tags: vba

I have a Cell range `Sheets("INVOICE MAKER").Range("D18:D37")` (Total 20 Cells), and a little **UserForm** with name **Add Items**.

In **UserForm** there are one **Textbox** and one **Submit Button**.

So if I write something in that **Textbox** and click on **Submit Button**, Data should be write to next available empty cell in range `Sheets("INVOICE MAKER").Range("D18:D37")`. And if all 20 cells are filled with data then show a message like **"No more rows are available to write data"**.

Below code don't start writing data from **`Cell D18`**, its start writing data from **`D1`**.
and doesn't stop after cell `D37`.

```
Option Explicit
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("INVOICE MAKER")

lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    
'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.Textbox.Value) = "" Then
  Me.Textbox.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please Type Item Name"
  Exit Sub
End If

With ws
  .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.Textbox.Value
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help!

**EDIT #1**
Fix some errors, and the code must to be inside a `Form`, with the `TextBox` and the `Button`

**EDIT #2**
Added a closing statement for the `userform` or the macro

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INVOICE MAKER") 'Set from Thisworkbook
    ws.Activate 'activate the Invoice Maker
    'lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    Dim iniCell As Integer: iniCell = 18
    Dim endCell As Integer: endCell = 37
    Dim setCol As Integer: setCol = ws.Range("D1").Column
    'As you said, the range is D18:D37, then you can manipulate from this 3 vars
    Dim iRange As Range
    Dim i As Range
    Dim isTheRangeFull As Boolean: isTheRangeFull = False
    Dim iMsgbox As Integer

    If Trim(Me.TextBox.Value) = "" Then
        Me.TextBox.SetFocus
        'Ask the user to retry or quit.
        iMsgbox = MsgBox("Please Type Item Name" & Chr(10) & "Do you want to retry?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1)
        If iMsgbox = 6 Then
            GoTo InsertData
            'if the user say YES
            'do it again
        ElseIf iMsgbox = 7 Then
            End
            'if the user say NO
        End If
    End If
    Set iRange = ws.Range(Cells(iniCell, setCol), Cells(endCell, setCol))
    'set your working Range
    
    'This Loop do the job!
    For Each i In iRange
        isTheRangeFull = True
        'if there is no empty cell, won't enter the if, and
        'the var continue TRUE, so there is no empty cells...
        If i.Value = Empty Then
            i.Value = Me.TextBox.Value
            isTheRangeFull = False
                'the Next line (End) Will close the Form and terminate the macro
            'End
                'The next line just close the userform
            'Unload Me
                'Decide which one to uncomment.
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    If isTheRangeFull Then
        MsgBox "No more rows are available to write data"
        End
    End If
    'With ws
    '  .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox.Value
    'End With
InsertData:
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply Mr @ElbertVilliarreal. 
For this line **Dim setCol As Integer: Range("D1").Column**, VBA says **"Compile Error: Invalid use of property"**

Comment: Thank you Mr. @ElbertVillarreal and **Mr. na4su**. Both answer are working good. But Stack Overflow doesn.t allow accepting both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hope below code will help you:

```
Public Working_Sheet As Worksheet
Public All_Cell_Value As Boolean
Public Write_Cell_No As Integer
Public Content As String

'When button in the form is clicked
Sub Button1_Click()
Write_Content
End Sub

'validation and content writing function
Public Function Write_Content()
All_Cell_Value = True
Set Working_Sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 18 To 37

If Trim(Working_Sheet.Cells(i, "D")) = "" Then
All_Cell_Value = False
Write_Cell_No = i
Exit For
End If

Next i

If All_Cell_Value = False Then
Content = InputBox("Enter the value")
If Content = "" Then
MsgBox ("No Data")
Else
Working_Sheet.Cells(i, "D").Value = Content
End If

Else
MsgBox ("Sorry content is full")
End If


End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. @na4su and **Mr. ElbertVillarreal**. Both answer are working good. But Stack Overflow doesn.t allow accepting both answers.